# median of a list

Tags: python, list

Write a program that receives from the keyboard a series of integers and positive numbers in ascending order. The program should stop receiving numbers when the input is a negative number. The program should then print the median of the series of numbers on the screen.

program on python

here what i already did:

```
import statistics
  
lst = []
n = int(input())

while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n < 0:
        break

median = statistics.median(lst)
print("Median of the given range is :", median)
```

Comment: If someone is making you use Python 2 in 2022, you would probably do well to wonder if you're in the right place, especially if this is used for teaching (which appears to be the case here?)  Having said that, what have you tried so far? Please share your code and explain what step you're stuck on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: You're not putting your inputs into a list. You need `lst.append(n)`.

Comment: can you explain me how i do this?

Comment: You can do it [this way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Please, read the links that were suggested to you in previous comments, and also [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This is a HW question, copy-pasting your code and correcting it takes less effort than giving you a hint. If experienced programmers choose the later, it's to help you for real.

Answer (score 0):

For line 4, `n = int(input())` is not needed as line 7 will change the value of n. Therefore, remove line 4 and add a new line `lst.append(n)` to append the input n into the list.

I believe this was what you were going for:

```
import statistics

lst = []

while True:
    n = int(input())
    lst.append(n)
    if n < 0:
        break


median = statistics.median(lst)
print("Median of the given range is :", median)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO has guidelines on [how to answer HW questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). In brief, hinting the student in comments and not giving the full solution serves two purposes: helping the student to actually develop their skills and also avoiding to make SO some kind of "coding-service".